# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar entre dos ventanas con Tkinter sin usar clases ni frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

Actualmente tengo dos scripts en python, y necesito abrir desde uno el a través de un botón, pero además pasando parámetros, he intentado hacerlo con clases o frases, pero no me ha resultado.

Script 1: Menu

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()

# Limpiar registros con botonLimpiar
def valoresLimpiar(*args):
  varDes.set('Seleccionar...')
  varModo.set('Seleccionar...')
  varEst.set('Seleccionar...')

# Obtener Valores con botonSimular
def valoresSimular(*args):
  print(varDes.get())
  print(varModo.get())
  print(varEst.get())

# Variables
varDes = StringVar(main)
varDes.set('Seleccionar...')

varModo = StringVar(main)
varModo.set('Seleccionar...')

varEst = StringVar(main)
varEst.set('Seleccionar...')

main.title("Configuración")
main.configure(background = 'light grey') # Color de Fondo

# Caja texto
labelOpciones = Label(main, bg = "light grey", text = 'Ventana Deslizante', padx = 30, pady = 5, width=20)
labelOpciones.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
labelOpciones2 = Label(main, bg = "light grey", text = 'Modo de Transmisión', padx = 30, pady = 5, width=20)
labelOpciones2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
labelOpciones3 = Label(main, bg = "light grey", text = 'Estrategia de Transmisión', padx = 30, pady = 5, width=20)
labelOpciones3.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

# Caja de Opciones
opciones = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
ventanaDeslizante = OptionMenu(main, varDes, *opciones)
ventanaDeslizante.config(width=20)
ventanaDeslizante.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 30, pady = 30)
opciones2 = ['NRM','ABM']
ventanaModoTrans = OptionMenu(main, varModo, *opciones2)
ventanaModoTrans.config(width=20)
ventanaModoTrans.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 30, pady = 30)
opciones3 = ['GoBack-N','Repetición Selectiva']
ventanaEstTrans = OptionMenu(main, varEst, *opciones3)
ventanaEstTrans.config(width=20)
ventanaEstTrans.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 30, pady = 30)  

# Botones Limpiar y Simular
botonLimpiar = Button(main, text="Limpiar", width=20, command=valoresLimpiar)
botonLimpiar.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 30)
botonSimular = Button(main, text="Simular", width=20, command=valoresSimular)
botonSimular.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 20, pady = 30)

main.mainloop()
```

Lo que necesito es que el botón que dice simular abra otra ventana, y se cierre así mismo, la otra ventana debería tener un botón atrás, para poder lograr hacer lo mismo.

Uno de los problemas que tuve al intentar usar clases fue que no sabía donde colocar las variables, o como hacerlas globales para usarlas entre clases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, ten en cuenta que solo debes tener una ventana principal y un solo mainloop por hilo. Para tu ventana secundarias deberías usar `tkinter.Toplevel`.

Por otro lado, el código de tu ventana secundaria para poder estar en otro módulo y poder pasarle los datos necesarios, necesita estar englobado en una función a la que puedas llamar desde el módulo principal. Si la defines a nivel de módulo se ejecutará al importar.

Podría ser algo así:

**secundaria.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk
import functools



def simular(parent, vent, modo, est):
    top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
    top.title("Simulación")
    top.geometry("400x200+0+0")

    info = tk.Label(top, text="Ventana: {}\nModo: {}\nEstrategia: {}".format(vent, modo, est))
    info.pack()

    top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", functools.partial(volver, parent, top))
    btn_volver = tk.Button(top,text="Volver", command=functools.partial(volver, parent, top))
    btn_volver.pack()

    parent.withdraw()

def volver(parent, top):
    parent.deiconify()
    top.destroy()
```

y en tu módulo principal:

```
import secundaria

def valoresSimular(*args):
    secundaria.simular(main, varDes.get(), varModo.get(), varEst.get())
```

El método `withdraw()` nos permite ocultar temporalmente la ventana principal, mientras `deiconify()` la vuelve a mostrar. Por su parte, `top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", func)` permite llamar a una determinada función cuando se presione el botón de <kbd>X</kbd> de la ventana hija, en este caso se actúa igual que al pulsar el botón <kbd>volver</kbd>.

Se que no quieres usar clases, pero es sin duda una mejor forma de estructurar tu código y hacerlo más reutilizable. Te voy a dejar una versión usando POO con algunos cambios más. Como nota, usar *wildcard* para importar (`from tkinter import *`) es generalmente una mala práctica y debe evitarse.

**secundaria.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk


class VentanaSimulacion(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, vent, modo, est, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title("Simulación")
        self.geometry("400x200+0+0")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.volver)

        info = tk.Label(self, text="Ventana: {}\nModo: {}\nEstrategia: {}".format(vent, modo, est))
        info.pack()

        tk.Button(self, text="Volver", command=self.volver).pack()
        self.parent.withdraw()

    def volver(self):
        self.parent.deiconify()
        self.destroy()
```

**main.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk
import secundaria


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Configuración")
        self.configure(background='light grey') # Color de Fondo

        # Variables
        self.var_des = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.var_des.set('Seleccionar...')

        self.var_modo = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.var_modo.set('Seleccionar...')

        self.var_est = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.var_est.set('Seleccionar...')

        # Caja texto
        label = tk.Label(self, bg="light grey", text='Ventana Deslizante',
                         padx=30, pady=5, width=20
                         )
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        label = tk.Label(self, bg="light grey", text='Modo de Transmisión',
                         padx=30, pady=5, width=20
                         )
        label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        label = tk.Label(self, bg="light grey", text='Estrategia de Transmisión',
                         padx=30, pady=5, width=20
                         )
        label.grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Caja de Opciones
        opciones = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
        menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.var_des, *opciones)
        menu.config(width=20)
        menu.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 30, pady = 30)
        opciones = ['NRM','ABM']
        menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.var_modo, *opciones)
        menu.config(width=20)
        menu.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 30, pady = 30)
        menu = ['GoBack-N','Repetición Selectiva']
        menu = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.var_est, *opciones)
        menu.config(width=20)
        menu.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 30, pady = 30)  

        # Botones Limpiar y Simular
        boton = tk.Button(self, text="Limpiar", width=20, command=self.valores_limpiar)
        boton.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=30)
        boton = tk.Button(self, text="Simular", width=20, command=self.valores_simular)
        boton.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20, pady=30)

    def valores_limpiar(self):
        self.var_des.set('Seleccionar...')
        self.var_modo.set('Seleccionar...')
        self.var_est.set('Seleccionar...')

    def valores_simular(self):
        secundaria.VentanaSimulacion(self.parent,
                                     self.var_des.get(),
                                     self.var_modo.get(),
                                     self.var_est.get()
                                     )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainWindow(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias!!! me sirvió bastante

Comment: Tengo una consulta, supongamos que quiero dar de alta un producto X.Entonces estoy en la ventana principal y me dirijo a otra ventana para agregar un producto , cuando vuelvo a la ventana principal tendria los datos que guarde en su ventana hija?

Answer (score 0):

BUeno lo que podrias hacer es crear varias ventanas , pero le modificas la geometria para que se ubiquen fuera de la ventana.

Normalmente tanto en TCL como en tkinter la geometría de una ventana tiene 4 parámetros wxh+px+py w es el ancho h es la altura px es la posición inicial en x de la ventana y py es la posición inicial en y de la ventana.

Pero con el px puede ser el doble del ancho, lo que consigues es que se mueva a una parte donde no se ve 2*w y con el boton "anterior ventana lo que haces es mover la ventana a la geometria de la pantalla para que se pueda ver.

cada ventana la dibujas con todos los widgets que desees.

cuando tengas listas la ventanas le pones una geometria fuera de la pantalla donde no se vea.

el boton anterior o siguiente no destruye ventanas, simplemente las saca del area de donde se vean.

esto pasa tan rapido que vas a creer que se cerraron pero no siguen funcionando fuera de la vista del programador.