# Abrir ventana una desde otra ventana y cerrar la primera

Tags: python, tkinter

Como puedo hacer para abrir una ventana desde la ventana principal y cerrar la ventana principal para que solo quede abierta la segunda?

Lo que intente:

```
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk

class venPrincipal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventanaPrincipal = Tk()
        self.ventanaPrincipal.geometry("500x500")

        abrirvenSecundaria = tk.Button(self.ventanaPrincipal, text="Abrir ventana secundaria",command=venSecundaria)
        abrirvenSecundaria.pack()

class venSecundaria:
    def __init__(self):
        #Abrir otra ventana y cerrar la primera

        print("Abrir otra ventana y cerrar la primera")

venPrincipal().ventanaPrincipal.mainloop()
```

Comment: Te recomienda esta pregunta, quizás te pueda ayudar... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332726/como-llamar-otra-ventana-en-tkinter

Comment: Hola Franco, aparte de la pregunta enlazada por Miguel te puede ser útil: [¿Cómo puedo cambiar entre dos ventanas con Tkinter sin usar clases ni frames?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/267045/15089). En mi respuesta al final hay un ejemplo usando POO que debería anclarte bastante tu duda, no obstante ante cualquier problema no dudes en comentar. La clave son los métodos `withdraw()` para ocultar y `deiconify()` para volver a mostrar si es necesario. La ventana principal no debes destruirla solo ocultarla, si creas más ventanas 2ª y solo las vas a usar una vez si puedes destruirlas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Pruebe este código, puede ser lo que busca. Saludos

```
from tkinter import *

def funcion():
      Otraventana.state(newstate = "normal")
  root.state(newstate = "withdraw")

def funcion2():
      Otraventana.state(newstate = "withdraw")
  root.state(newstate = "normal") #state(newstate = "withdraw")root.deiconify, zoomed()


root = Tk()
root.state(newstate = "normal")
root.geometry("250x150+300+100")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("Ventana 1")

abrirVentana2 = Button(root, text="Abrir ventana 2", bg="green", font= ("Times New Roman", 12), fg="yellow", command=funcion)
abrirVentana2.pack()

Otraventana = Toplevel()
Otraventana.state(newstate = "withdraw")
Otraventana.geometry("250x150+300+100")
Otraventana.title("Ventana 2")

miEtiqueta = Label(Otraventana, text="Bienvenido a la ventana 2", bg="#252850", font=("Times New Roman", 12), fg="yellow")
miEtiqueta.pack()

abrirVentana1 = Button(Otraventana, text="Abrir ventana principal", bg="green", font= ("Times New Roman", 12), fg="yellow", command=funcion2)
abrirVentana1.pack()


Otraventana.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```